# scss basics: inheritance with nesting

Tags: inheritance, sass

I have this structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <p>Some content</p>
    <div class="anothersub">
      <p>Some content with <a href="#">a link</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Say I want to apply a color to all the children contained in a div elements.

I thought that the nesting feature of scss means that I can get all the text in white by writing something like this:

```
.container {
  color: white;

  .subcontainer {
    // other rules
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .anothersub a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

But instead it looks like I have to copy the color: white; to each and every div, p and a element. Or do I miss something (sass newbie here)?

Comment: Your text *should* all be white because color is inherited by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Scss really, this is just basic css.

Setting the text colour on the .container element *is* all you need to do to set the text colour for all the child elements, Scss or not, as the styles cascade (CSS).

I suspect that you are seeing your links are not white but this is because they have additional styles (including colour) specified by browsers stylesheet (and possibly also in your css). So you do need to also specify a link colour.

You can do this easily with Scss by using:

```
.container {

    &,
    a {
      color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Which will be compiled to:

```
.container { color: #fff;}
.container a {color: #fff;}
```

Comment: Yes, the culprit was in the another part of another stylesheet. Thank you for the tip!